# Notification: как вернуть активность которая не в фокусе,а не создавать новое?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать уведомление которое вызываю в :

```
@Override
    public void onPause(){
         Notify();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

В манифесте активити прописано:

```
android.permission.GET_TASKS"
```

в текущей активти

```
<activity
            android:name=".fragment2"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
 />
```

Код уведомления,которое выводится в статус бар,уведомленеи работает, однако по нажатию на уведомления открывается новая копия активити ,а не текущая,которая свернута и не в фокусе

```
NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;
     public void Notify() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),fragment2.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setAutoCancel(false);
            builder.setTicker("Потешки-колыбельные");
            builder.setContentTitle("Колыбельные");
            builder.setContentText("Сейчас играет:");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_playback_play);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.setSubText("Описание");   //API level 16
            builder.setNumber(100);
            builder.build();
            myNotication = builder.getNotification();
            manager  = (NotificationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(100, builder.build());
                }
```

Полный код:
    public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

```
    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
    static final String TAG = PageFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    ImageView[] arr_imageA = new ImageView[3];
    ImageView[] arr_imageB = new ImageView[7];
    ImageView fab;
    Animation anim;
    boolean isClicked;
    Toast toast;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int pageNumber;
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;

    private int[] soundsRawResIds = new int[] {R.raw.belarus, R.raw.russian, R.raw.ukraina,
            R.raw.litva, R.raw.england, R.raw.japan, R.raw.france};
    private int[] buttonIds = new int[] {R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5 ,R.id.b6, R.id.b7};
    private int[] fragments = new int[]{R.id.imageView1,R.id.imageView2,R.id.imageView3};
    private String [] names = new String[]{"Беларусь","Россия","Украина","Литва","Англия","Финляндия","Франция"};


    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
        fab();
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);


    }


        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            arr_imageA[i] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(fragments[i]);

            arr_imageA[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                   // mediaPlayer.start();
                    playSample(R.raw.click_sound);
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.imageView1:

                            startActivity(getActivity(), a1.class);


                            break;

                        case R.id.imageView2://todo копипаст
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a2.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView3:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a3.class);
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            if (pageNumber == 1) {
                View rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }



                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {
                    arr_imageB[j].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            v.startAnimation(anim);
                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.b1:
                                {

                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
                                         }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b2:

                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);

                                        }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b3:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);

                                        }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b4:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                                         }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b5: {
                                    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                                }
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b6: {
                                    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);

                                }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b7:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);

                                        }
                                break;
                            }

                            return false;  }

                    });
                }

                return rootViewB;

            }


        }

        return rootView;
    }
    public void startActivity(final Context activityContext, final Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(activityContext, activityClass));
            }
        }, 200);
    }
    private void fab(){
        fab = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
        final Animation anim_fab = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab_animation);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fab.startAnimation(anim_fab);
                //если isClicked возращает true
                fab.setImageResource(isClicked ? R.drawable.speaker_icon_on_shadow :
                        R.drawable.speaker_icon_off_shadow);
                float volume = isClicked ? 1.0f : 0f;
                setVolume(volume, volume);
                toast.makeText(getActivity(), isClicked ? R.string.sound_on : R.string.sound_off,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isClicked = !isClicked;
            }
        });
    }




    private void playSample(int resid) {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            afd.close();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void stopPlayerIfNeeded() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }


    public void setVolume(float left, float right) {
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(left, right);
    }

   @Override
    public void onPause(){
        /*if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }*/
       Notify();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){


        super.onResume();
    }


    public void Notify() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),fragment2.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker("Потешки-колыбельные");
        builder.setContentTitle("Колыбельные");
        builder.setContentText("Сейчас играет:");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_playback_play);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSubText("Описание");   //API level 16
        builder.setNumber(100);
        builder.build();
        myNotication = builder.getNotification();
        manager  = (NotificationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(100, builder.build());

    }

}
```

Comment: А если добавить `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),fragment2.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());

новая активность открывается,т.е я нажимаю кнпоку назад и вижу активность,которая должна была загрузиться

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил полный код в шапку

Comment: Ну... Вообще, не видно никаких ошибок... Попробуйте создать чистый проект, в нём активити, в нём кнопку, по кнопке запустите уведомление с указанными флагами. Должно будет заработать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
так метод работает,только возвращает он новое активити,а не старое ....подозреваю,что с фрагментами как-то иначе нужно работать и уведомления посылать

Comment: У вас в интенте что-то странное... `Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),fragment2.class);` там должно быть что-то типа `ActivityMain.class`, а у вас какой-то фрагмент, да и тот с маленькой буквы... Т.е. вообще не пойми что написанное не по правилам и вне ожиданий метода.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 
getContext() т.к мой основной класс
public class PageFragment extends Fragment
вызываю:
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
что не так я делаю?)